# How I can insert multiple data records returning from subquery (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

- Populate `PRODUCT_ID` column of `CC.TRIDENT_PRODUCT_CODES` with PRODUCT_CODE of `PRODUCTS.PRODUCT` table.
- Mapping is `CC.TRIDENT_PRODUCT_CODES.PRODUCT_CODE = LEGACY_PRODUCT_CODE`

```
update
    CC.TRIDENT_PRODUCT_CODES tpc
set
    tpc.PRODUCT_ID = (
        select
            product_code
        from
        (
            SELECT 
                pp.product_code,
                ROW_NUMBER() over  ( PARTITION BY LEGACY_PRODUCT_CODE order by LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP ) as RANK
            FROM
                products.product        pp,
                trident_product_codes   tpc 
            WHERE
                tpc.product_code IN pp.legacy_product_code
                AND
                pp.legacy_product_code IS NOT NULL
        ) 
        where
            rank = 1
    );
```

I am getting following error :

> SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
> 01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

I checked subquery separately and it returning 18 rows now I need to insert these rows into `CC.TRIDENT_PRODUCT_CODES.PRODUCT_ID` one by one. I know the reason of error message its because subquery returning multiple records and can not update into the next table but I need solution to fix this problem.

Comment: please a a complete [mre]  for your problem. But as you use partition, you must have more than one LEGACY_PRODUCT_CODE, also try to use proper joins

Comment: `update` doesn't *insert* rows, so I really don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: there are rank 1 for every partition that is why it doesn't work. You have to change your update query to join the product id and find an `ON` clause which put the product id at the right place, as nobody knows your data nobody can help you only hints like i did

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert multiple row of data matched into same row.

That is not posible.